# Carousel controllers don't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I copy this carousel code from Bootstrap page and I edit contents of the carousel.

But controllers don't work
even though I move controllers inside the " div " element.

( But it works if I test it in a blank page with only carousel.)

When I test this code in my working page , they don't work

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   <meta name="description" content="">
   <meta name="author" content="">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
   <title>Thai Chiang Mai</title>

   <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
   <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

   <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
   <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-3.2.1.min.js">

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img/food/bonchon.jpg" alt="bonchon" style="width:100%;" class="img-responsive">
      </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/food/green_curry.jpeg" alt="Curry" style="width:100%;" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/food/kai.jpg" alt="Kai" style="width:100%;" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: are  you sure you don't have any other code on the page? looks like it works for me. http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/BRdpog

Comment: I'm not seeing bootstrap.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use js and jquery before ending body tag.
And use single framwork. You are using two w3 and bootstrap.